# Issues with messageid and putting reaction collectors on proper message in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm attempting to make an embed in discord that updates when a reaction is pressed on said embed. this is what I have attempted so far:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    //  if (message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    let msg = message.content.toLowerCase();

    if (msg === 'test2') {
        message.channel.send(embed)
         .then(async embedmsg => 
        await embedmsg.react('⚔️')).then(() => {
            let collector = embedmsg.createReactionCollector(() => {
                return true;
            }, {
                dispose: true,
            });
            collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
                let emojiName = reaction.emoji.name;
                if (user.id == bot.user.id) return;
                if (emojiName != '⚔️') return;
                console.log('here')
                embedmsg.edit(newEmbed1)
```

everything seems to work, but I'm receiving the error msg

```
(node:58428) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createReactionCollector' of undefined
```

and yes I have declared var embedmsg.
If I change the line:

```js
let collector = embedmsg.createReactionCollector(() => {
```

to:

```js
let collector = message.createReactionCollector(() => {
```

it only runs the collector on the original 'test2' message, which cannot be edited due to the fact that it was not sent by the bot. Any tips would be much appreciated! It is probably a super easy fix due to the fact that I haven't coded in a very long time.

Comment: Is the bot reacting correctly?

Comment: yes! the bot is adding a react to the embed, not test2, which confused the hell out of me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`embedmsg` is no longer defined because you closed the `.then()` method.

```js
 message.channel.send(embed)
         .then(async embedmsg => 
        await embedmsg.react('⚔️'))
//                                ^^
// since you ended the callback, embedmsg is no longer defined.
             .then(() => {
```

---

Instead, use:

```js
message.channel.send(embed).then(async (embedmsg) => {
  await embedmsg.react("⚔️").then(() => {
    let collector = embedmsg.createReactionCollector(
      () => {
        return true;
      },
      {
        dispose: true,
      }
    );
  });
}); // close the callback down here instead
```

Comment: Thank you so much! now the only error I'm encountering is that the collector is not defined, which doesn't seem to make much sense to me, but will attempt to debug tonight ```(node:60064) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: collector is not defined``` adding in a var collector; only shifts the error to ```(node:62644) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined``` meaning the collector somehow became undefined

Comment: You're putting `collector.on` right below the collector declaration, right?

Comment: ... I had an extra }... yep works perfectly! Thank you so much for dealing with the infuriating and simple oversights!

Comment: Haha no problem